# Using SSIS to query ADO .NET source query passing in parameters from SQL Server

Tags: mysql, sql-server, ssis

I would like to pass parameters to a MySQL query using ado.net as the source of the query.

```
SELECT *  
FROM   userinfo
WHERE  load_date > '2012-01-07' 
AND    load_date < '2012-01-14'
```

I have a settings table in sql server that has my values:

```
SELECT  startdate, enddate 
FROM   tblsetting
```

I have managed to pass these values into SSIS. If I run a query against my sql server tables I am able to use this:

```
SELECT *  
FROM    userinfo
WHERE   load_date > ? 
AND     load_date < ?
```

But when I change my source to ado.net, connecting to mysql server , it does not like that syntax. Can anyone explain what am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

You can write a SQL expression and store it a variable of type `String`

```
"SELECT *  
 FROM    userinfo
 WHERE   load_date > '" +  (DT_WSTR,20) @[User::YourDateTimeVar]  + "''
 AND     load_date < '" +   (DT_WSTR,20)@[User::YourDateTimeVar]  + " ' "
```

and then use this variable for a property which is present in the expression of `Data Flow Task` .Write click on DFT and select Properties . Click on Expression and select `Ado.NET sql command` from the properties in the dialogue box

[image]

Select the variable for the above property.Here `ADO_SRC_Orale[SqlCommand]` property will be replaced by the name of your `ADO.NET source`

[image]